# Why does printf require a mandatory parameter?

Tags: c, printf

The definition of printf function in C Language is:

```
int printf(const char * _Format, ...);
```

The same is for `scanf` and a lot of similar functions where is managed a variable number of arguments.

Why is there a `_Format` mandatory parameter?

Comment: Because otherwise a call would be a no-op?

Comment: The question puzzles me; how would the desired format be given to the function otherwise? Would you prefer overloads to for the formatted output of every single elementary data type?

Comment: Because there' s no point in calling the function if there's no parameter passed to it.

Comment: I think the question is why there is no overload for just passing 1 argument that will be printed. ex: "printf(i)" instead of "printf("%d", i)"

Comment: Functions with a variable number of arguments need at least one.  Macros with a variable list of parameters can be defined to take 0 or more.  You can remove all `printf` output by defining `#define printf(...)`

Comment: @Onur - There is no overloading in C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Yes. I thought that is the answer of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format string is mandatory because the way C's variable argument macros work depends on at least one argument being present, and using it to find the others.

Specifically, to read the other variable arguments, you use `va_start` (then `va_arg` repeatedly, once for each variable argument you want to read). When you call `va_start`, you need to pass it the format string (or, more generally, the last non-varying parameter to the function).

For example, this acts like `printf`, but prints to both `stdout` and another file of your choice:

```
void tee(FILE *f, char const *fmt, ...) { 
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(f, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

This uses `vprintf` and `vfprintf`, so it doesn't (directly) use `va_arg` itself, only `va_start` and `va_end`, but that's enough to show how the `fmt` is involved in using `va_start`.

At one time, this wasn't actually needed. Back when C was shiny and new, you could have a function equivalent to: `int f(...);`.

During the first C standardization effort, however, this was eliminated in favor of the macros noted above (`va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`) that require at least one named parameter. The older macros placed a number of requirements on the calling convention:

1. Parameters are always passed the same way, regardless of type or number.
2. It's always easy to find the *first* argument that was passed.

With the conventional C calling convention (all arguments are passed on the stack, arguments are pushed from right to left) this was true. You basically just looked at the top of the stack, moved backward past the return address, and there was the first argument.

With other calling conventions, things weren't so simple though. For example, just pushing arguments from left to right means that the first argument (the format string, in the case of `printf`) is buried some arbitrary distance down the stack, with an arbitrary number of other arguments after it.

The way they came up with to deal with that was to pass the immediately previous (named) argument to `va_start` (and va_start is a macro that will normally use the address of that argument). If you push from right to left, that will give you an address whatever distance needed down the stack, then `va_arg` can walk back *up* the stack to retrieve the other variable arguments.

This was apparently seen as an acceptable compromise, especially since functions that take variable arguments almost always take at least one named parameter anyway.

Comment: I would be better to explain how the arguments popup from the stack works instead of using varargs routines to better understand and explain the meaning of the required parameter. In any case I apreciate your answer. Thank you

Comment: @gaemaf: The arguments do not necessarily come from the stack ;-) but I agree a simpler example would be helpful.

Comment: While true, this answer misses the more fundamental point and delves into what are essentially implementation details -- being a standard function, `printf` need not be implemented in terms of `va_start`, etc.

Comment: The fundamental point is much simpler - the format string is what tells `printf` what to do and specifically what types to expect in the variadic arguments. If it were optional, there would be no way to determine anything about the number or type of arguments passed.

Comment: @R..: If you keep it specific to `printf`, that's true. That still leaves the possibility of things like: "I want to pass a list of integers, terminated by some special value (e.g., 0 or -1)", which wouldn't require a format string, or anything very similar.

Answer (score 4):

Because it doesn't want to guess what to print

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory because `printf` is used *to print data*. Imagine what'll happen if you print nothing. *Nothing*. So, why to remove that parameter?

That's the same thing about `scanf`: you need to *read data somehow* and how are you going to do it if you don't know the format of this data?

Some functions don't have parameters because they don't need them, eg

```
void Hello(void) { puts("Hello"); }
```

So, they can *'survive'* without parameters. About `printf`:

```
int printf(void) { //imaginary function, don't use it!
    // WTF? What to print?
    // Absolutely nothing! What's the purpose then?
    return smth;
}
```

Then *this `printf`* is **absolutely useless when no arguments are passed**.

Answer (score 1):

In general, functions that have an unknown number of arguments rely on `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` to process the arguments that are not explicitly in the function's parameter list.

`va_start` needs the last named parameter to work with. Hence, a function that has an unknown number of arguments must have at least one named argument.

For `printf` the parameter/argument that specifies the format specification is the best choice as the required parameter/argument.

Answer (score 0):

Without a format description, printf wouldn't understand what to print. To C, everything is just bytes, so printf has no idea what kind of data is being passed to it, and therefore no idea how to represent it.

When you're new to C, you might not yet realize how true this is, especially if you've learned a language where print() understands the type of data it's seeing.